# Rendering application.html.erb-like layout for a new namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

I'm building a custom Admin section for my app, and I'd like for the `:admin` namespace to have its own layout.

So far I've been playing with this in app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  layout :cond_layout

  def cond_layout
    if controller_path.split("/").first == "admin"
      "panel"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

which a friend told me to use, but it smells really fishy. Besides Semantic-UI stopped working in the admin namespace. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a way, a clean one I believe.
Define a new layout called `foo`. Then an Admin Controller like this:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  layout "foo"
  before_action :bar
end
```

And now every controller that inherits from `AdminController` will render the `foo` layout and will execute the `bar` action.

Answer (score 1):

If you have and you probably have some Admin::MainController.rb too in admin namespace? Then don't hesitate to override layout there. Imho, much cleaner..